# Generic Typescript Type + React hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript-generics, use-reducer

I have the following http hook:

```
export const useHttp = <T,>(initUrl: string, initData: T) => {
    const [url, setUrl] = useState(initUrl);
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(fetchReducer, {
        isLoading: false,
        error: '',
        data: initData
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        let cancelRequest = false;

        const fetchData = async (cancelRequest: boolean = false) => {
            if (!url) return;

            dispatch({ type: 'API_REQUEST'});
            try {
                const responsePromise: AxiosPromise<T> = axios(url);
                const response = await responsePromise;
                if (cancelRequest) return;
                dispatch({ type: 'API_SUCCESS', payload: response.data });
            } catch (e) {
                console.log("Got error", e);
                dispatch({ type: 'API_ERROR', payload: e.message });
            }
        };
        fetchData(cancelRequest);

        return () => {
            cancelRequest = true;
        }

    }, [url]);

    const executeFetch = (url: string) => {
        setUrl(url);
    };

    return { ...state, executeFetch}
};
```

Reducer:

```
const fetchReducer = <T,>(state: IState<T>, action: TAction<T>): IState<T> => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'API_REQUEST':
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true
            };
        case 'API_SUCCESS':
            return {
                ...state,
                data: action.payload,
                isLoading: false,
                error: ''
            };
        case 'API_ERROR':
            console.error(`Triggered: ${API_ERROR}, message: ${action.payload}`);
            return {
                ...state,
                error: action.payload,
                isLoading: false,
            };
        default:
            throw Error('Invalid action');
    }
};
```

actions:

```
export interface IApiSuccess<T> {
    type: types.ApiSuccess,
    payload: T;
}
export type TAction<T> = IApiRequest | IApiSuccess<T> | IApiError;
```

Using like this:

```
const { data, error, isLoading, executeFetch } = useHttp<IArticle[]>('news', []);

return (
        <>
            <div className={classes.articleListHeader}>
                <h1>Article List</h1>
                <small className={classes.headerSubtitle}>{data.length} Articles</small>
            </div>
            <ul>
                {data.map(article => <Article article={article}/>)}
            </ul>
        </>
    )
```

My TS yell at me because I'm using the `data` variable: `Object is of type 'unknown'.  TS2571`

I did specify the type of the useHttp which is IArtlce[].
Any idea what i'm missing?

Update:
I tried to add return type for my reducer:

```
interface HttpReducer<T> extends IState<T> {
    executeFetch: (url: string) => void
}

export const useHttp = <T,>(initUrl: string, initData: T): HttpReducer<T> => {
```

but I get:

```
Type '{ executeFetch: (url: string) => void; error: string; isLoading: boolean; data: unknown; }' is not assignable to type 'HttpReducer<T>'.
```

Comment: Try adding a type to the `state`. Or add a return type to the custom hook.

Comment: What do you mean by adding type to the `state`? My state parameter has `IState<T>` type.

Comment: that's not mentioned in the question... did you try adding a return type?

Comment: how is `fetchReducer` typed?

Comment: @RameshReddy Not sure how I can add such type for my case. Updated my question with example

Comment: @thedude Added it aswell (updated question): `const fetchReducer = <T,>(state: IState<T>, action: TAction<T>): IState<T> => {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to [reproduce your error](https://tsplay.dev/w26z9w).  You are expecting that the `useReducer` hook will be able to infer the state type based on the type of the initial state, but it's just inferring `IState<unknown>`.

The types for `useReducer` [are defined](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/bca409da017f8523bd95355614d5d2b1a480082b/types/react/index.d.ts#L965) such that the generic argument is the type of the reducer.  The type for the state is inferred from the reducer with the `ReducerState` utility type.  It's not expecting a generic reducer and doesn't work well with it.

There is no relation between the `T` of the hook and the `T` of the reducer rather than the state.  `fetchReducer` is a generic function which means that it can take *any* `IState` and return an `IState` of the same type.  We can use this function to process the `IState<T>` of our hook, but in order to infer the type of the state we need to say that our function will *only* accept and return `IState<T>`.

You need to set the generic on you `useReducer` to this:

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer<(state: IState<T>, action: TAction<T>) => IState<T>>( ...
```

---

On the surface this looks very similar to what's being inferred right now, which is:

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer<<T,>(state: IState<T>, action: TAction<T>) => IState<T>>(...
```

But the difference is critically important.  The current describes a generic function while the fix describes a function that only takes one type of `T` -- that of the `useHttp` hook. It's misleading because you are using `T` for both.  Perhaps it is easier to see if we rename one.

We *had* a generic function:

```
export const useHttp = <Data,>(initUrl: string, initData: Data) => {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(initUrl);
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer<<T,>(state: IState<T>, action: TAction<T>) => IState<T>>(fetchReducer, {
```

We *need* a specific use case of that function:

```
export const useHttp = <Data,>(initUrl: string, initData: Data) => {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(initUrl);
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer<(state: IState<Data>, action: TAction<Data>) => IState<Data>>(fetchReducer, {
```

When we know that our reducer state type is `IState<Data>`, then we know that the type of `data` is `Data`.

Now calling `useHttp<IArticle[]>()` gives you a `data` variable with type `IArticle[]`.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/NBz5VN)