# redux-saga "call" effect not typing saga params correctly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-saga

I have a saga defined as the following:

```js
type GenericFunction = (...args: any[]) => any;

interface IFetchSaga<T extends GenericFunction> {
  saga: T,
  args: Parameters<T>
}

function* triggerChange<T extends GenericFunction>(fetchSaga: IFetchSaga<T>, shouldFetch: boolean) {
  // ...do stuff
  if(shouldFetch) {
    yield call(fetchSaga.saga, ...fetchSaga.args);
  }
  // ...do stuff
}
```

---

When I try to use this saga inside another one, using the `call` effect I am not getting the correct typing for the `IFetchSaga` args:

```js
function* fetchData(id: number, date: string) {
  // ...do fetch
}

function* load() {
  // ...do stuff
  yield call(triggerChange, {
      saga: fetchData,
      args: ['10', '2021-03-22'] // I don't get an error saying that '10' should be a number
    },
    true
  );
}
```

For instance, when I try to execute it directly (as if it was any other function), the typing works correctly:

```js
triggerChange({
  saga: fetchData,
  args: ['10', '2021-03-22'] // Here I get the error saying that '10' should be a number
});
```

#### **Is there anything I can do to get the args typing correctly when calling my saga?**

---

Ps.: I know I can define my `fetchSaga` param outside of the call effect, but then I would have to always call the `IFetchSaga` with a `typeof` (and I would like to avoid it):

```js
function* fetchData(id: number, date: string) {
  // ...do fetch
}

function* load() {
  // ...do stuff
  // This would work, but I want to avoid having to do it 
  const fetchSaga: IFetchSaga<typeof fetchData> = {
    saga: fetchData,
    args: ['10', '2021-03-22'] // Get the typing error for '10'
  };

  yield call(triggerChange, fetchSaga, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

My suggestion to fix this is to create the `IFetchSaga<T>` object through a helper function.

```
function fetchable<T extends GenericFunction>( saga: T, ...args: Parameters<T>): IFetchSaga<T> {
  return {saga, args};
}
```

You could pass the args as an array if you want to.

This allows typescript to easily infer the proper args for the function and make sure that they match.

```
function* load() {
  // error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'
  yield call(triggerChange, fetchable(fetchData, "10", "2021-03-22"), true);
  // okay :)
  yield call(triggerChange, fetchable(fetchData, 10, "2021-03-22"), true);
}
```

---

#### Problem

The reason that the original version fails is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66737391/10431574) where I go more in depth. `triggerChange` is a generic function that can be called with any `T`.  When we are creating a `call` effect for `triggerChange` it does not need to have any particular `T` type since the `T` is determined at the time when the function is called.  The type for the arguments falls back to just `GenericFunction` where `args` are `any[]`, so there is no issue with assigning your array to that.

Our solution works because we are inferring a specific `T` by directly calling `fetchable`.  It's the `fetchable` function that gives us errors -- not the `call`.  If we were to declare that the `fetchable` `T` is just `GenericFunction` then we would have the same issue as before.

```
// no errors, even though we want them
yield call(triggerChange, fetchable<GenericFunction>(fetchData, "10", "2021-03-22"), true);
```